# Remove all files dropzoneJs only image upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

How I can remove images after sendingmultiple without removing other params? I tried this but it does not work:

```
init: function () {
            this.on('sendingmultiple', function(file, xhr, formData){
              formData.append('ids', $("#ids").val());
            });
          },

init: function () {
            this.on("completemultiple", function (file) {
              this.removeAllFiles();
            });
          },
```

**I do not want to delete this id, just images**

Comment: Are you trying to restrict uploads to only image files?

Answer (score 0):

In drop zone above the following function use

```
 function isImage($img){
    return (bool)getimagesize($img);
 }
 if(isImage($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){ 
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetFile))
```